# Error for respawn enemy and player script unity 4 version

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with this script that gives me errors. My project consists of respawn the player and the prefab enemies after being destroyed after 5 seconds in the same original position but the script gives me a lot of errors and I don't know how to fix them. can you give me some help to correct the script? Thanks

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class respawn : MonoBehaviour {

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    StartCoroutine(Respawn(5f, 5f));
}
 
IENumerator Respawn(float timeToDespawn, float timeToRespawn) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToDespawn);
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
    gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You spelled `IEnumerator` wrong. The `N` needs to be lowercase. Consider using an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). That would have detected your mistake and would also give you huge lot of help developing. I suggest either [Microsoft VisualStudio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) or [Jetbrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/)

**Edit:**
Your object still won't respawn because when you disabled the object, the coroutine will be stopped since it's part of that gameobject. Instead you could use [invoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html). It continues when your gameobject gets disabled.
Thisshould work:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class respawn : MonoBehaviour {

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    Invoke(nameof(Despawn), 5f);
    Invoke(nameof(Respawn), 10f);
}

void Despawn(){
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
} 
 
void Respawn(){
    gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
}
```

As you can see Invoke simply delays the execution of a method.

Comment: Tanks I fix my error but the prefab don' respawn

Comment: I edited my answer to fix that problem too

Comment: in these lines I find the error but  I really don't be able to fix it 
   Invoke(nameof(Despawn), 5f);
   Invoke(nameof(Respawn), 10f);

Answer (score -2):

script gives me many errors and doesn't work. How Can you fix it, please?

Assets/respawn.cs(7,12): error CS0103: The name `nameof' does not exist in the current context Assets/respawn.cs(7,5): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for` UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour.Invoke(string, float)' has some invalid arguments
Assets/respawn.cs(7,5): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert` object' expression to type `string' Assets/respawn.cs(8,12): error CS0103: The name` nameof' does not exist in the current context
Assets/respawn.cs(8,5): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour.Invoke(string, float)' has some invalid arguments Assets/respawn.cs(8,5): error CS1503: Argument` #1' cannot convert `object' expression to type` string'

Comment: Hi, please, befor post a question, try to explaining a little bit more of what you want to do, the steps you took to get int this situation and then, using the code formatting  editor past the error.  If you keep just throwing texts and asking for someone fix it wont work.  Its a collaborative forum not a customer support.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can't tell you why it doesn't work but you can replace nameof() with just the method name with quotationmarks for example: Invoke("Respawn", 5f);